# iOS - Filter array of objects which contains today's date only

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, filter

Basically my challenge is :

I got an array of objects . Each object has a date property .
I want to get the array of objects which matches today's date.

So, I want to group the array based on date.

I want to show in history list by grouping objects from today, yesterday, last 7 days ,.....

---

I can sort array using sort function:

```
historylist.sort(by: {$0.createdDate! as Date > $1.createdDate! as Date })
```

But I need a filter function based on date. 
I want all the data in historicist which are created today only.

Any quick pseudo code .

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo of how this works with filtering `date objects`:

```
let d1 = Date().addingTimeInterval(22000000)
let d2 = Date().addingTimeInterval(23000000)
let d3 = Date().addingTimeInterval(30000000)
let dates = [d1, d2, d3, Date(), Date()]

let calendar = Calendar.current
let todayDates = dates.filter({calendar.isDateInToday($0 as Date)})
print(todayDates) // [2017-06-03 15:50:11 +0000, 2017-06-03 15:50:11 +0000]
```

**So in your case you should do it like this:**

```
let todayDates = historylist.filter({calendar.isDateInToday($0.createdDate as Date)})
```

**Update:**
To convert a `string` to a `Date` use the following:

```
extension String {
    var toDate: Date {
        return Date.Formatter.customDate.date(from: self)!
    }
}

extension Date {
    struct Formatter {
        static let customDate: DateFormatter = {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
            return formatter
        }()
    }
}

let strDate = "06-01-2017 09:32:48 PM"
let date = strDate.toDate
```

Comment: What´s the string sample, need it to write the format for you @user3804063

Comment: sure it is like this: 06-01-2017 09:32:48 PM

Comment: yeah sure but i had database structured with date as string , 
so i wanted to know if I can filter dates (which are string )

i can change the database for another alternative but it will take time as my project is complicated.

it's 1 june @Rashwan

Comment: How can I filter objects from yesterday ?

Comment: @user3804063, added code of how to convert String to Date. To get dates from tomorrow, use isDateInTomorrow instead of `isDateInToday` use `isDateInYesterday`.

Comment: And for last week and last month , is there any property ??

Comment: In the `calendar.isDateInToday` remove `.isDateInToday` and add a `.`and you´ll see all properties available in there.

Answer (score 4):

```
let date1 = NSDate()
let date2 = NSDate()
let dates = [date1, date2]

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let todayDates = dates.filter({calendar.isDateInToday($0)})
```